# Combining two raster layers into one vector points layer with two attributes

Tags: qgis

I have two raster layers, which I need to use to make a scatterplot. I can't find any tools that will let me produce a scatterplot from two raster layers, but there appear to be a few tools for producing a scatterplot from vector data.

So I'm trying to convert the two rasters into one vector points layer, with the values from each raster stored as attributes against each point. Is this possible, and how would I go about it? I've been googling all afternoon and can't work it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the QGIS Processing Toolbox, there is a SAGA tool `Raster Values to points` (under `Vector <-> raster` group).

The tool extracts cell values from multiple rasters and put them into a point shapefile `Shapes`. Each raster is represented by a field, which fieldname following the raster filename.

[image]

Comment: Fantastic. So simple - can't believe I didn't spot that in the toolbox. I had to remove the alpha bands from my input rasters but once I'd done that this worked perfectly. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I suggest, also, to use *SAGA GIS* because it's a more stable software; especially if you want to process big raster files. In this software the tool is labelled *grid to point*.